# Efecto extraño del css

Tags: css

Estoy haciendo una pequeña web y de pronto me ha surgido un problema que no sé identificar.

Creo que es css, pero ni siquiera estoy seguro. El caso es que tengo una pagina con cuatro imagenes y al hacer hover en ella, las imagenes crecen un poco. Hasta ahí todo bien, hasta hoy solo tenía 3 y ningún problema. Pero hoy he actualizado la web para añadir una cuarta y he aquí el problema, en Chorme (al menos en Firefox no ocurre) la cuarta imagen adquiere como una especie de brillo extraño durante la transición, y sinceramente, no tengo ninguna pista de que puede ser.

http://www.londonsportingclub.com/ --> Es ahí, en la parte baja, para ser más concreto la imagen de Michael Johnson.

Cualquier sugerencia será más que bien recibida. Gracias!

Comment: No veo nada raro, se ve igual que todas, pero de de antemano te recomiendo que pongas tu código para que se pueda revisar

Comment: ese como chispeo cuando sacas el foco?

Comment: Gracias Javi! No sé, quizá solo me pasa a mí en chrome, pero en mi caso es como si se pixelara mucho, hasta que toma las dimensiones finales y se vuelve a ver bien. Como ya he dicho en Firefox se ve perfectamente, por eso pensé que quizá sería cosa del CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un bug que lleva años en Chromium; algunas ganan ruido, otras blur, etc., y algunas funcionan bien. De hecho, la tercera imagen también tiene ese ruido (quítale la animación del fondo para que lo puedas ver).

Este problema se puede disminuir considerablemente este comportamiento mediante `filter` y `translateZ`:

```
.workbox:hover > img {
  filter: blur(0);
  transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
}
```

El eje Z se encarga de la *profundidad* del elemento en un plano 3D, lo que hacemos con `translateZ(0)` es evitar que se modifique este valor en el repixelamiento que hace el navegador.

**PD:** es importante que agregues prefijos para `filter` para aumentar compatibilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias Gustavo! Voy a probar a ver qué tal. Es cierto que la tercera también lo tiene, pero se le nota menos por lo evidente. Mil gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Funcionó  perfectamente! Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada. Recuerda marcar mi respuesta como correcta (check debajo de los votos) para indicar que mi respuesta te ayudó.

Comment: Hecho! Es la primera vez que uso el foro y estoy algo perdido, así que agradezco mucho la ayuda :)